# В зависимости от выбранной кнопки переход на разные страницы JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

[image: как это выглядит]

Интересует каким методом реализовать. При нажатии на кнопку Continue должен происходить переход (в новой вкладке) на разные страницы:
Если пользователь выбрал 1-ю опцию (1 month), то переход дожен быть на страницу https://q=10
, если 2-ю то https://q=20 и т.д.

Comment: чую можно сделать средствами form/radio без JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open("your url" + "/q=" + document.querySelector('.contract.selected').dataset.qvalue);
```